# How do I debug Powershell Desired State Configuration not generating MOF files?

Tags: windows, powershell-v4.0, dsc

I'm following the most [basic example on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249918.aspx) and I'm failing to get it to work. I've got my configuration defined as follows:

```
Configuration MyWebConfig
{
   Param($ComputerName)

   Node $ComputerName {
      WindowsFeature MyRoleExample
      {
          Ensure = "Present"
          Name = "Web-Server"  
      }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to generate MOF with `C:\Scripts> .\IisWithCompressionConfig.ps1 -ComputerName "localhost" -Outputpath C:\Scripts\localhost` (and couple other command line variants). I'm not getting any file output and no errors are reported (exit status code is also 0). I've tried a version without the `$ComputerName` variable (and instead "localhost" hardcoded), still nothing. Yes, I'm running this in an elevated prompt.

I've made sure that I'm running PowerShell 4.0:

```
C:\Scripts> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                            
----                           -----                                                                                            
PSVersion                      4.0                                                                                              
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                              
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                          
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34003                                                                                  
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16394                                                                                   
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                                                                             
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With DSC, I dot source the configuration definition into the current session, then call it.

```
# dot source will load PS1 into current session
. .\IisWithCompressionConfig.ps1
# Then call the config
MyWebConfig -ComputerName "localhost"
```

Configurations are quite similar to functions, that is you'd want to call `MyWebConfig` (config) not `IisWithCompressionConfig` (file).  In fact, defined DSCs will be in the `Function:` PSDrive. Try running the following both before, and after, you dot source your PS1.  Before, you should see no results, after, you should see `MyWebConfig` in the `Function:` PSDrive.

```
Get-ChildItem Function:* | Where-Object { $_.CommandType -eq 'Configuration' }
```

---

In the provided TechNet example, they're using the ISE.  In step 4 they're defining (instead of sourcing) the `MyWebConfig` config right in the current PS session.  This is functionally equivalent to dot sourcing the PS1 file.  Right after step 6, they call `MyWebConfig`, which generated the MOF.

Comment: D'oh. You're right! In my defense, that article is not very clear on that detail.